# E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648) E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648) D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648 errors can't play .mp4 video format

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

the android studio can't play .mp4 format
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Vn4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIcEb.png)

can any one tell me what's wrong
plus these errors showed up E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648) E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648) D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648 errors

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome King Wolverine, Add errors of logs (logcat) in your post. Add code don't it't image.